# Find network information

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to find my computer's network information with Python and i use psutil. I get the result like this :

```
{'Local Area Connection* 2': [snic(family=-1, address='34-F3-9A-4C-D0-C5', netmask=None, broadcast=None, ptp=None), snic(family=2, address='169.254.189.147', netmask='255.255.0.0', broadcast=None, ptp=None), snic(family=23, address='fe80::b83c:382a:1976:bd93', netmask=None, broadcast=None, ptp=None)], 'Ethernet': [snic(family=-1, address='C8-5B-76-AC-B7-BC', netmask=None, broadcast=None, ptp=None), snic(family=2, address='10.164.200.11', netmask='255.255.255.0', broadcast=None, ptp=None), snic(family=23, address='fe80::28db:c0b:3d58:9aba', netmask=None, broadcast=None, ptp=None)], 'Wi-Fi': [snic(family=-1, address='34-F3-9A-4C-D0-C4', netmask=None, broadcast=None, ptp=None), snic(family=2, address='192.168.1.102', netmask='255.255.255.0', broadcast=None, ptp=None), snic(family=23, address='fe80::5c61:43a3:f2d6:c994', netmask=None, broadcast=None, ptp=None)], 'Local Area Connection* 4': [snic(family=-1, address='00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0', netmask=None, broadcast=None, ptp=None), snic(family=23, address='2001:0:9d38:90d7:1093:131:3f57:fe99', netmask=None, broadcast=None, ptp=None), snic(family=23, address='fe80::1093:131:3f57:fe99', netmask=None, broadcast=None, ptp=None)], 'Loopback Pseudo-Interface 1': [snic(family=2, address='127.0.0.1', netmask='255.0.0.0', broadcast=None, ptp=None), snic(family=23, address='::1', netmask=None, broadcast=None, ptp=None)]}
```

I try to get connection name and corresponding ip, netmask, mac address. But I can't  get it. When i use for loop, key of this dict is only thing i get :

```
def NETWORK():
netinfo = psutil.net_if_addrs()
for connection_name in netinfo :
    print connection_name
```

The result is :

```
Local Area Connection* 2
Ethernet
Wi-Fi
Local Area Connection* 4
Loopback Pseudo-Interface 1
None
```

And i try to access value of those key by this ways but not success :

```
print netinfo['address']
print connection_name['address']
print connection_name.address()
```

Please tell me how to access this dict and get the connection name and corresponding ip, netmask, mac address.
Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is a dict format output. So, you need to access the values by key.

When you run the command, you get 'en0' ,'en1' etc as keys.

```
>>> out = psutil.net_if_addrs()
```

out will be a dict. Therefore, in order to obtain info of 'en0' ,use

```
>>>out['en0']
```

This will give a list of `snic` objects. You can loop through them and get the data as follows

```
>>> for a in out['en0']:
...     print(a.address)
```

This will give the various address.
TO access other key info, use `a.netmask`

Comment: Thanks bigbount, but how can i separate ipv4, ipv6 and MAC address ? Cause all those key name "address". I only want to get connection name and corresponding ipv4, netmask and mac address. For example : 
Wifi :
IPv4 : 192.168.1.10
Netmask : 255.255.255.0
MAC : 34-F3-9A-4C-D0-C4